# Android databinding setText() over model binding

Tags: android, android-databinding

In my xml I have a line `android:text='@{entry.printTitle}'`

In my adapter I set entry: `binding.setEntry(item);` in `bind()` method.

For some occasions I want to set that field manually with `binding.entryTitle.setText("some other title")`, but it doesn't work. How can I set that field without affecting entry, which is immutable?

Comment: then u need to abandon from data binding here and just set in bind method manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not override values of binding variables. If you want change dependent views, you have to change its variable value.

You can take another variable for this purpose. And set value in this second variable when you want. Just make this second variable null when you have done.

```
android:text='@{entry.fakeTitle ?? entry.printTitle}'
```

Now when you  want change title but not its variable then set value in `fakeTitle`.

```
binding.getEntry().setFakeTitle("testing");
```

When you have done make it null so text will be `printTitle` again.

You have to use [`ObservableField<String>`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableField) or [`LiveData`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata), if you are changing value programmatically. If you are extending by [`BaseObservable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/BaseObservable) then you have to make `fakeTitle` `@Bindable` and [notify after changing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35075630/6891563).